# how to update a node in xml using C# on basis of ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, nodes, parent

I am trying to update a node in Xml on basis of ID which I am getting in C#.

My xml file looks like this ::::   Name of Xml : Contact.xml

```
<CATALOG>
 <CD>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <HeaderDetailID>1</HeaderDetailID>
    <FirstName>Basant</FirstName>
    <LastName>Gera</LastName>
    <EmployeeID>0012</EmployeeID>
    <Department>SD</Department>
    <Postion>Programmer</Postion>
    <Application>Balance***BI_AP_KL_BALANCE</Application>
    <Filter>Africa_ww_READ</Filter>
    <AreaorCountryorStation>India</AreaorCountryorStation>
    <NetworkDomain> Area / Country / Station Code </NetworkDomain>
    <Action>
      Modification
    </Action>
    <NameOfController>Area</NameOfController>
    <Status>New Request</Status>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <HeaderDetailID>1</HeaderDetailID>
    <FirstName>Ankush</FirstName>
    <LastName>Tyagi</LastName>
    <EmployeeID>0013</EmployeeID>
    <Department>SD</Department>
    <Postion>Programmer</Postion>
    <Application>Balance***BI_AP_KL_BALANCE</Application>
    <Filter>Alps</Filter>
    <AreaorCountryorStation>India</AreaorCountryorStation>
    <NetworkDomain> Area / Country / Station Code </NetworkDomain>
    <Action>
      Modification
    </Action>
    <NameOfController>Area</NameOfController>
    <Status>New Request</Status>
  </CD>
  <CD>
</CATALOG>
```

I am getting the id in my hidden field and than I want to update the node of Status to a string "Request Completed"

So I need to change this node

```
<Status>New Request</Status>
```

to the node this

```
<Status>Request Completed</Status>
```

On the basis of Id which I am getting.

I am trying to code like this below:

```
 protected void btnTemp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     string iIDs = hdnData.Value;
     string[] DateData;
     DateData = hdnData.Value.Split(';');

     for (int i = 0; i < DateData.Length - 1; i++) {
         string iRecordID = DateData[i];

         XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
         string  filepathsUpdate = Server.MapPath("~/Contact.xml");
         xmlDoc.Load(filepathsUpdate);
         XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/CATALOG/CD[@ID=" + iRecordID + "]");
         node.Attributes["Status"].Value = "Request Completed";
         xmlDoc.Save(filepathsUpdate);
     }
}
```

But here I am getting my node null. Why I am not able to update a node on basis of ID

Comment: XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/CATALOG/CD[ID=" + iRecordID + "]/Status");

Answer (score 2):

According to me you are missing single quote `'` while selecting the SingleNode. Your code should be like this

```
XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("CATALOG/CD[@ID='" + iRecordID + "']");
```

Please update the above code.

It should work.

Thanks

Comment: It woked like this also

Comment: it woked like this also                                                                         
 XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/CATALOG/CD[ID=" + iRecordID + "]/Status");

Comment: But using `node.Attributes["Status"].Value = "Request Completed";` should still cause an error since `Status` is a child node of `CD` and not an `Attribute` of that node, right?